# Is there a way to divert logs/errors to run code in pm2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I want to be able to run code to log the error correctly then crash the process instead of immediately crashing the process if there is an error, like a global try catch.
Is there a way to do that?
I want a solution like

```js
process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
    logTheErrorSomehow();
    process.exit(1);
});
```

but that doesn't work in pm2, only node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of trial and error, I came across this solution that worked:

```js
const pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.launchBus(function(err, pm2_bus) {
  pm2_bus.on('process:exception', function(packet) {
    await logTheErrorSomehow(packet);
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

This works just like `process.on("uncaughtException")` did with node.